# Cannot connect to RemoteNG Client. Check if old version of testng.jar is being used error-Eclipse Luna

Tags: testng-eclipse

I am getting an error like -

```
Cannot contact RemoteTestNG Client.Make sure you do not have older versions of testing.jar on your classpath.
Reason:Timeout while trying to contact RemoteTestNG.
```

I tried various solutions already present in stack overflow:

- Check "Use project testng" option
- Add latest testing.jar in classpath.
- Check for duplicate testng jars in classpath.
- Delete old testNG testsets ,clean workspace and restart workspace

But all the above solutions did not work for me and I ended up getting the same error again.

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

the latest release of testng eclipse [6.9.11](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/blob/master/CHANGES.md#6911) should fix this issue, please let me know (or fire an issue here https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues)

Noted: since this version, option "Use Project TestNG jar" was removed, to always respect the Project's TestNG lib.